# Method that receives LINQ IGrouping as Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

**Edit 3:Improved question wording and examples**

I have the following linq query that uses grouping. The grouping and select operations are complex, so I abstracted one of the selects to a method that makes some choices on how to render the data.

My query works correctly inside the anonymous group definition, but as soon as I type it to a class in order to pass it to a method as an IGrouping object it stops grouping the results.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult ThisWorks()
    {
        var valueList = DataMocker.GetTestValues();

        var group = from v in valueList.AsEnumerable()
                    where (v.Data != 0)
                    group v by new 
                                   {
                                       Year = v.Fecha.Value.Year,
                                       Trimester = string.Empty,
                                       Month = v.Fecha.Value.Month,
                                       Day = 0,
                                   }
                        into g
                        select new SeriesDataPoint
                                                     {
                                                         y = g.OrderByDescending(obd => obd.Fecha)
                                                                  .Select(obd => obd.Data.Value)
                                                                  .FirstOrDefault(),

                                                         color = "black",
                                                         month = g.Key.Month,
                                                         year = g.Key.Year,
                                                         seriesName = "Test Series",
                                                     };

        return Json(group, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult ThisDoesnt()
    {
        var valueList = DataMocker.GetTestValues();

        var group = from v in valueList.AsEnumerable()
                    where (v.Data != 0)
                    group v by new Models.SeriesResultGroup
                    {
                        Year = v.Fecha.Value.Year,
                        Trimester = string.Empty,
                        Month = v.Fecha.Value.Month,
                        Day = 0,
                    }
                        into g
                        select new SeriesDataPoint
                        {
                            y = RenderDataPoint(valueList, g),
                            color = "black",
                            month = g.Key.Month,
                            year = g.Key.Year,
                            seriesName = "Test Series",
                        };

        return Json(group, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public static decimal? RenderDataPoint(List<Models.ValoresResultSet> valores, IGrouping<Models.SeriesResultGroup, Models.ValoresResultSet> group)
    {
        return group.OrderByDescending(obd => obd.Fecha)
                    .Select(obd => obd.Data.Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

- This is the correct output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9764/Thisworks.txt
- This is the wrong output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9764/ThisDoesnt.txt

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error description. Please explain what is happening. If you get an error message, post it. If you don't get the desired result, post the expected and actual result.

Comment: Your code in this question does not match the code in the file you are linking to.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm sorry, wasn't explicit enough. The code compiles and runs, but the grouping doesn't work as expected. In fact, it doesn't work at all and I get all rows back

Comment: a grouping doesn't filter anything, so it comes as no surprise that you get all rows. Still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @juharr I reduced the code in the above example in order to not clutter the whole screen. I'll update it with the correct one.

Comment: @amhed I only mentioned that because my first thought was that you were passing a grouping on an anonymous class into your function, which would not work.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm doing some Average operations using the grouping. But they don't consider the group when called from inside the method. If I take the same arguments and lay directly in the query they work, but if I relegate them to the method they don't

Comment: @juharr I had to type the group in order to pass it to an external function, but I got something wrong and the grouping isn't happening

Comment: @pkmiec I'm sure it's a mess, but it's with I have to work with. It was worse than it is now and I'm trying to first separate everything into more logical components and then do refactoring.

Comment: Please try to strip it down to something reasonable so we can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth just updated the question. Here is the MVC4 project in case you want to run it and look at the results: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9764/StackOverflowExample.7z

Comment: what is Models.SeriesResultGroup ? If it is a class without overriden Equals, then each object is unique in terms of equality

Comment: @NechytailoOleh Models.SeriesResultGroup is a typed class that I made. It's just a class with property definitions: int Year, string Trimester, int Month, and int Day. Do I ned to override Equals in order for the grouping to work?

Comment: @NechytailoOleh that seemed to do the trick!! Why does this happen explicitly with anonymous objects and not with typed ones?

Comment: Hi Ahmed. What can really help in situations like this is for you to keep removing from your method until it is as simple as possible, yet still demonstrates the problem. At the moment it's quite unclear.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I updated the contents of the question and striped it down to its most basic form. Someone commented that I should implement IsEqual for the class I'm using to group by, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you group by anonymous type, generated by compiler. This type also has generated Equals and HashCode overrides (you can check it via ildasm). Anonymous type`s default Equals runs equality comparer for each field. I think this was made for use in cases like this.

In second case you group by your custom type. Since it is a reference type, default equality comparer compares objects by reference. Because before grouping you produce a sequence of objects, each of them is unique. So default equality check thinks that they differs.

Solutions are (choose any):

1. Override Equals and HashCode.
2. Make type `struct` instead of `class`

Be careful and don`t forget to implement HashCode as well.